# Exception when wrapping asyncio.gather

Tags: python, python-asyncio, wrapper

I experimented with asyncio.gather as follows:

```
async def some_work(work_name, timeout, raise_exception=False):
    """Do some work"""
    print(f"Start {work_name}")
    await asyncio.sleep(timeout)
    if raise_exception:
        raise RuntimeError(f"{work_name} raise an exception")
    print(f"Finish {work_name}")


async def main():
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(
            some_work("work1", 3),
            some_work("work2", 1),
            some_work("work3", 2),
            asyncio.gather(
                some_work("work4", 3),
                some_work("work5", 1, raise_exception=True),
                some_work("work6", 2)
            )
        )

    except RuntimeError as error:
        print(error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

At some point, I decided to make a wrapper over asyncio.gather like this:

```
# Yes I know, concurrently really
def in_parallel(*aws, loop=None, return_exceptions=False):
    return asyncio.gather(aws, loop, return_exceptions)
```

and use it like this:

```
async def main():
    try:
        await in_parallel(
            some_work("work1", 3),
            some_work("work2", 1),
            some_work("work3", 2),
            in_parallel(
                some_work("work4", 3),
                some_work("work5", 1, raise_exception=True),
                some_work("work6", 2)
            )
        )

    except RuntimeError as error:
        print(error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

And got a bunch of errors:

> D:/Archive/Projects/PycharmProjects/test/asyncio_gather.py:34:
>   RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'some_work' was never awaited   in_parallel(
>   RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation
>   traceback Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/Archive/Projects/PycharmProjects/test/asyncio_gather.py", line 46,
>   in 
>       asyncio.run(main())   File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
>       return loop.run_until_complete(main)   File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 612, in
>   run_until_complete
>       return future.result()   File "D:/Archive/Projects/PycharmProjects/test/asyncio_gather.py", line 34,
>   in main
>       in_parallel(   File "D:/Archive/Projects/PycharmProjects/test/asyncio_gather.py", line 14,
>   in in_parallel
>       return asyncio.gather(aws, loop, return_exceptions)   File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 806, in gather
>       fut = ensure_future(arg, loop=loop)   File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 673, in ensure_future
>       raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is ' TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is
>   required sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'some_work' was never
>   awaited

Can anyone explain why? It's just a wrapper!

Comment: You need to unpack ``aws`` again when passing them on.

Comment: If the issue is resolved, it is expected to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/627709). This rewards the volunteer who wrote it with token reputation, and it also removes the question from the list of open questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why? It's just a wrapper!

The wrapper has the proper signature, but it's not correctly invoking `asyncio.gather`:

```
def in_parallel(*aws, loop=None, return_exceptions=False):
    # XXX incorrect invocation of `gather`
    return asyncio.gather(aws, loop, return_exceptions)
```

[`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) expects awaitables to be passed as positional arguments, which is how you were invoking it in the first version of your code. As you invoke it from the wrapper, you are always passing it exactly three positional arguments: `aws` (containing a tuple of awaitables passed to `in_parallel`), `loop` (always `None` as you invoke it), and `return_exceptions` (a boolean). None of those is an actual awaitable, so `gather` raises an exception as soon as it tries to do something with the "awaitables" it received, such as converting them to futures.

The correct way to invoke `gather` from `in_parallel` is to use the `*` operator to pass each element of `aws` as separate positional argument, and to pass `loop` and `return_exceptions` as keyword arguments:

```
def in_parallel(*aws, loop=None, return_exceptions=False):
    return asyncio.gather(*aws, loop=loop, return_exceptions=return_exceptions)
```

With this modification, your code works as expected. Finally, note that explicit `loop` argument is [deprecated](https://bugs.python.org/issue36373), so you can omit it from your wrapper.

Comment: what is aws here?